# raspberry pi cloud or NAS server

Tags: linux, networking, nas

soon i will have a raspberry pi and i would like to transform into a cloud server or a NAS server just to have all my files through the network, the problem is that i have to be able to access it outside of my LAN using both windows and linux.

I was thinking about something like samba cause like that i was able to divide diffent hard disk to different username

since i don't have it already i haven't tried something yet.

i was wondering if there's a secure way (for example with encryption of data) to do it and what's the best to start.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use a shared folder in your network using SMB, you can make it accessible using a VPN-server on your router that lets you tunnel outside traffic into your local network.

Alternatively you can host a cloud service on a prefab NAS or a Raspberry Pi, like [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org/) ([still very slow for a large number of files](https://github.com/owncloud/core/issues/20967)) or [SeaFile](https://www.seafile.com/en/home/) (should perform much better), and install the clients on every computer where you need your files to keep those files in sync with the 'cloud' (which is just in your home on a device).

There are numerous guides online that show you how to setup both services on a Raspberry Pi, if you don't mind getting your hands a little dirty by setting up a linux image on your Pi. For a NAS like a Synology Diskstation, things will be simpler still.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Samba is the correct way to share files between very different OSes.

As for securing it, you may wish to read [this Web page](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/securing-samba.html), which mostly deals this securing samba shares. A reasonable precaution to take (but please read to the end for a way to do without all of this) is to set `server signing = [auto|mandatory|disabled]` in the Global section of the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file: [the Manual](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html) states:

> **server signing (G)**
>
> This controls whether the client is allowed or required to use SMB1 and SMB2 signing. Possible values are auto, mandatory and disabled.
>
> When set to auto, SMB1 signing is offered, but not enforced. When set to mandatory, SMB1 signing is required and if set to disabled, SMB signing is not offered either.
>
> For the SMB2 protocol, by design, signing cannot be disabled. In the case where SMB2 is negotiated, if this parameter is set to disabled, it will be treated as auto. Setting it to mandatory will still require SMB2 clients to use signing.
>
> Default: server signing = Disabled

If instead you are worried about a third party reading your communication, and thus the content of your files, then you might, at least in line of principle, use application-layer utilities (like GnuGP) to encrypt/decrypt files, so that you would be transferring on an open line only encrypted files, with no one being able to read them in your stead.

However, a better solution is to setup a [Virtual private Network (VPN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network). This would guarantee *both* encryption *and* secure identification. My personal favorite is [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/); I have setup an OpenVPN server on my Raspberry PI running Raspian, and I can connect to it via clients (available for all OSes including Android and iOS) from anywhere. A VPN in general both authenticates clients, and encrypts its communication, so that you can asssign both of these features to the VPN, relieving SAMBA of both tasks. In partiular, a `bridged` OpenVPN makes your remote client appear **as if** it belonged to your local LAN, and then you could use, as only security for Samba, that its clients belong to your local LAN.

Plus, a VPN can be configured to give you access to whichever service you have at home, ssh/telnet/rdp sessions with your local pcs, printers, domotics, and so on.

Comment: Why is samba better than ftp?

Comment: @jiggunjer More control.

Comment: isn't samba insecure via Windows since there's a lot of exploitation for Windows using it?

Comment: @FreedomSka That's why I am proposing to you to use a VPN: in this way, you would not need to expose Samba's ports to the Internet: there would be no port forwarding to do thru your router, and you could accept, on your Samba server, only **local** connections, *i.e.* within your LAN 192.168.0.0/24, or whatever you use.

Comment: So if i have understood good i will connect to the vpn from outside of my lan that will connect to my samba server?

Comment: @FreedomSka Yes: you connect to your home via the VPN; at this point your Samba share will appear on your pc  **as if** you were at home, where you normally see your Samba share. The first time you do this you will have to search for the share, from then on it will appear automatically.